# Facing issue while trying to renew my nexus cert

Tags: nexus

why i am getting error while updating cert of nexus "no cert in -in file matches private key : x509 certificate routines:x509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:405:

No File Format Issue
No mismatch in module
permissions also set
No Issue with Key and cert tried regenerating it but same issue persist
any solution to this issue?